# Eclipse Groovy change Color of Comments?

Tags: eclipse, groovy

How can I change the color of comments for groovy files in Eclipse?

The option is not available in the preference/editor settings.

Edit: I use Eclipse Kepler 4.3.1

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change the color in Java syntax coloring option in Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring > Comments, it will change Groovy's too.

Worked fine on Eclipse Juno.

Comment: So close :-) - the screen from the screen shot had the answer - just at the bottom of the screen - need to scroll to the bottom to see it.

Comment: @mikemil At the bottom is a button to copy the style from Java. It works but not for the comments.

Comment: My bad - guess I should have tried it before posting. :-(

Comment: @mikemil Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @confile - it worked for me.  I just changed the Editor->Syntax coloring - changed comments to purple and then opened Groovy file and the comment were purple.  Comment but NOT the Javadoc comments/content.

Comment: @confile, changing Java's comment colors didn't worked for you?